# Апплет на java

Tags: applet, java

Добрый день! Я третий день изучаю java. На работе дали следующее техническое задание:

Требуется создать java апплет со свойствами:

- Апплет предназначен для запуска с
     html страницы (в том числе не должно
     быть препятствий для использования на
     защищенных страницах - https).
- у апплета не должно быть видимой
     части на странице.
- доступ к функциям апплета с помощью
     javascript с html страницы.
- апплет должен предоставлять браузеру
     функцию readDir (string pDir) для
     перечисления файлов и папок по
     указанному пути с локального
     компьютера пользователя в качестве
     входного параметра функции.
- Если входной параметр функции передан
     в апплет пустой строкой, то следует
     вернуть список элементов из папки
     "Мой компьютер" (список съемных и
     несъемных носителей).
- функция readDir возвращает объект, у
     которого есть две функции: getCount()
     и getItem(number).
- getCount() возвращает кол-во
     элементов найденных в папке.
- getItem(number) - возвращает элемент
     с номером number.
- функция getItem должна возвращать
     объект содержащий сведения о: имени
     файла, типе файла (папка, диск или
     файл), размере файла в байтах, дате
     создания, дате изменения. Для
     получения каждого значения из объекта - отдельная функция.

Вот что получилось у меня после выполнения этого задания (после многочисленных поисков в интернете, вопросов на форумах, прочтения литературы и исходников по java):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute;
import java.lang.Object;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.LinkOption;

class FileInfo {
   public String NameFile;
   public String TypeFile;
   public int SizeFile;
   public Date DateCreate;
   public Date DateEdit;
}

class AttributFilesFolders 
{
   String path;
   private int count = 0;
   private int typefile = 0;

   private int FunctionTypeFile(File f)
   {
      if (f.isFile())
      {   
        //если элемент является файлом 
        typefile = 1;
      }
      if (f.isDirectory())
      {
        //если элемент является папкой   
        typefile = 2;  
      }

      if (f.getParent()==null)
      {
         //если элемент является диском
          typefile = 3;
      }

      if (!f.exists())
      {  
         // если элемент не существует 
         typefile = 0; 
      }
      return typefile;
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("null")
   public String[] ViewFolder()
   //Осуществляет обзор папки
   {
      String[] s = null; 
      File file = new File(path);
      if (path!="")
      {       
        String[] sDirList = file.list();
        for(int i = 0; i < sDirList.length; i++)
        {
          File f1 = new File(path + File.separator + sDirList[i]);
          switch (FunctionTypeFile(f1))
          {
              // если это файл пишем тип файл и имя файла          
              case 1:  
               s[i] = "-file-"+sDirList[i];
              break;
              // если это папка пишем тип папка и имя папки 
              case 2:
                  s[i] = "-dir-"+sDirList[i];     
              break;              
           }    
        }
      }
      else
      {
         // если переменная path пуста, то вернем список дисков 
         File[] arrayRoots = File.listRoots();
         int i = 0;
         for (File root : arrayRoots)
         {
           i++;
           s[i] = root.getPath();
         }
      }       
      return s; 
   }

   public FileInfo getItem(int number)
   //Возвращает элемент с номером number
   {
      FileInfo FI = new FileInfo();
      File file = new File(path);
      //BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.getAttribute(file, BasicFileAttributes.class, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
      int c = 0;

         File[] s = file.listFiles();
         for (int j = 0; j < s.length; j++)
         {   
            c++;
            if (c==number)
            {
               File f1 = new File(path + File.separator + s[j]);
               switch (FunctionTypeFile(f1))
               {
                  // если это файл, то получаем его аттрибуты
                  case 1:  
                    FI.NameFile = f1.getName();
                    FI.TypeFile = "file";
                    FI.SizeFile = (int) f1.length();
                    //FI.DateCreate = "";
                    FI.DateEdit =  new Date(f1.lastModified());
                    break;
                  // если это папка, то получаем ее атрибуты  
                  case 2:
                      FI.NameFile = f1.getName();
                      FI.TypeFile = "dir";  
                    break;
                 // если это диск, то получить ее атрибуты  
                  case 3:
                      FI.NameFile = f1.getName();
                      FI.TypeFile = "disk";
                    break;
               }        
            }       
         }

      // возвращаем данные объекта
      return FI;   
   }

   public int getCount()
   {
    /* Подсчет всех файлов и
     папок в каталоге
    */
    File file = new File(path);
    File[] s = file.listFiles();
    return s.length;

   }

   public int getAllCount()
   {
      /* Подсчет всех файлов и 
       папок во всех содержащихся 
       подкаталогах
      */
      File file = new File(path);
      File[] s = file.listFiles();
      for (int j = 0; j < s.length; j++)
      {
         if (s[j].isDirectory())
         { 
            path = s[j].getPath();
            getAllCount();  
         }
         count++;
      }
      return count;
   }
}

public class View_files_folders 
{
  public AttributFilesFolders readDir(String pDir)
  {
      AttributFilesFolders AFF = new AttributFilesFolders();
      AFF.path = pDir;
      return AFF;
  }
}
```

И соотвественно возникли финальные вопросы:

1. Грамотен ли этот код с точки зрения java-программиста?
2. Заметили вы какие-либо ошибки в нем, мне как новичку это важно знать?
3. На данный момент у меня это сохранено в файле `View_files_folders.java` как это превратить в апплет `View_files_folders.jar`? Просто откомпилировать в eclipse? Если так, то у меня почему-то не компилируется данный код, хотя ошибок нет...
4. Как из html страницы в которой есть поле ввода для текста (input) передать в апплет строку директорию в функцию readDir?
5. Как вернуть данные из апплета на страницу html и отобразить это? Например из функции ViewFolder() возвращающей массив строк вернуть в виде таблицы...

Простите за глупые вопросы возможно, просто я новичок совсем, начинаю только разбираться в java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Претензии навскидку:

1. В методе `FunctionTypeFile` вы используете "[магические числа](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))". Это дурной тон, создайте константы с говорящими именами.
2. Вообще, метод `FunctionTypeFile` написан неграмотно не только с точки зрения Java, но и сточки зрения программирования в общем. Если вы ничего не делаете с переменной, которую возвращаете, зачем вы её вообще заводите? Возвращайте значение сразу.
3. В классе `AttributFilesFolders` вы используете package-level поле `path`, значение которого устанавливаете вручную. Это грубое нарушение инкапсуляции, в идеале программисту не должны быть доступны никакие поля класса извне этого класса. В ситуации вроде вашей я бы посоветовал сделать поле `path` `private`, а его значение передавать в экземпляр класса через конструктор или сеттер (метод `setPath()`, устанавливаающий значение поля).
4. То же самое можно сказать про класс `FileInfo`. Обычно все поля класса делают private, а доступ к ним осуществляют через геттеры и сеттеры (методы `getИмяПоля()` и `setИмяПоля()`).
5. Старайтесь соблюдать [Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) - соглашения по именованию переменных, констант, классов, форматированию и оформлению кода. Это сделает ваш код более читаемым для других Java-программистов.
6. Не обязательно, но желательно, чтобы каждый класс лежал в отдельном файле (исключения для nested и анонимных классов).

Теперь про апплет. Апплетом в вашем коде даже не пахнет. В нём даже точки входа нет, поэтому запустить его ни в виде апплета, ни в виде обычной программы вы не сможете. Почитайте хотя бы [вот эту статью](http://www.helloworld.ru/texts/comp/lang/java/java/15.htm), возможно, станет понятнее. По поводу взаимодействия с апплетом со страницы, вот [статья](http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/js/js-java.php).

Comment: Насчет FunctionTypeFile согласен, поправил ее как сказали... Насчет path тоже подумаю над тем чтобы сделать это через конструктор или setPath(). За критику спасибо, я просто еще Java совсем не знаю... Да и с ООП программированием нечасто приходилось еще сталкиваться. Про апплеты, предстоит еще видимо разбираться...

Comment: Кстати заметил такую ошибку, когда я переделал FunctionTypeFile без переменной, а сделал напрямую return 1 и т.д. стало выдавать сообщение: This method must return a result of type int. Потому мне приходилось вводить переменную. Как тут быть?

Comment: У вас возможна ситуация, в которой все 4 `if`-а вернут `false`, соответственно, ваша функция ничего не вернёт. Нужен ещё один `return` в конце, который выполнится, если не выполнятся предыдущие.

Comment: понятно, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

1. Код на "троечку".
2. Туча ошибок, что бросается в глаза несоблюдение [Java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) и еще, где собственно `public class MyClass extends Applet` - то есть где апплет? Далее особенный перл это функция `FunctionTypeFile(File f)` - это жесть.
3. Читайте [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062941/build-project-into-a-jar-automatically-in-eclipse)
4. [Читайте доки](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html)
5. [Читайте доки](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html)

Comment: Туча ошибок в чем именно?

Comment: На троечку неудивительно, первая программа это.

Answer (score 1):

По поводу .jar файла: eclipse переводит твой код в машинный и запускает его, но только, как бы, внутри себя. А вот эти *.class файлы тебе и нужно собрать в .jar файл. Для этого, либо зайди в командную строку и выполни команду

> **jar -cf myfile.jar *.class**

из той папки, где у тебя расположены .class файлы.
Или можно использовать [maven](http://www.apache-maven.ru/) или [ant](http://ant.apache.org/)

Comment: спасибо за совет.